# How to get Current User Address in SocialEngine?

Tags: php, object, socialengine

I am trying to get the address field datas in SocialEngine.

I get the current user by:

```
$viewer = Engine_Api::_()->user()->getViewer();
```

I can get the fields array by the following:

```
$fields = Engine_Api::_()->fields()->getFieldsValuesByAlias($viewer);
```

which returns:

```
Array (
    [profile_type] => 23
    [first_name] => firstname
    [last_name] => lastname
    [birthdate] => 1994-1-1
    [gender] => 8
    [website] => www.website.com )
```

**Which object do I have to call to get the current user Address fields, such as City,State, ZIP code etc.?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've added city, state, zip fields etc. from control panel. You need to edit `engine4_user_fields_meta` table in database and manually add alias for those custom fields.

Comment: But the the alias name for city is already given in database but it doesnot shows in the array output. Why is that ?

Comment: Consider putting your site on development mode. It works OK for me.